# Multiple-boned meshes breaking when I move armature

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I'm trying to figure out why the area where two bones connect on a mesh will mess up when I pose the model around.

(normal) https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLba.png - (posed)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXR3N.png

armature modifiers https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3Fy.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single armature with the head and jaw bones in it. You shouldn't be making a new armature for each bone. The hierarchy in the armature should have the head bone as the parent of the jaw bone, so that when the head moves the jaw does too, but not vice-versa.

With the head bone armature selected, go to edit mode. Select the head bone, hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to duplicate it. Select the new bone that was created, rename it to **jaw** and move it to the jaw position. With the jaw selected, hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and add the head bone to the selection, and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to make the head the parent of the jaw. Choose **Keep Offset** otherwise the jaw will snap back to where the head bone is. Pay attention to the order things are selected when parenting. The first selected item(s) are the children, the last selected thing is the parent.